# Kendo templates remember first entered value

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Recently I encountered strange behaviour of Kendo templates. If you have an input in a template, the template will remember first entered value only. So, the value you enter is impossible to overwrite later.

I have the following template

```
    <script id="add-new-gruppe" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="span12" id="groupName" name="newGroupName" /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button class="add-new-gruppe btn btn-primary">OK</button>
            <button class="add-new-gruppe-cancel btn">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>​
```

The problem is, that if a user tries to add more than 1 group - he will never manage to do this, as only first entered name will be taken into account.

Here you can reproduce the issue (I based it on a delete-confirm example):

http://jsfiddle.net/x79yp/2/

- click "Delete record"
- enter 123
- click Yes
- you see alert with the value you just entered.
- click "Delete record"
- enter 345
- click Yes
- you see an alert with "123" instead of the entered value "345"

Either this is a very funny bug, or some specific behaviour.

Any ideas why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are create the window multiple times and not removing it. When the next time you ask for the `input` element you are getting the value of the first one (not the last just created).

Instead, consider this other code:

HTML

```
<button class="delete-button k-button">Delete record</button>
<script id="delete-confirmation" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <p class="delete-message"> Enter anything </p>
    <input class="span12" id='enteredText'/><br/>
    <button class="delete-confirm k-button"> Yes</button>
    <a href="#" class="delete-cancel k-button">No</a>
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var template = $("#delete-confirmation").html();
    // Create window once
    var kendoWindow = $("<div />").kendoWindow({
        title    : "Confirm",
        resizable: false,
        modal    : true,
        visable  : false
    }).html(template).data("kendoWindow");

    $(".delete-confirm", kendoWindow.element).click(function (e) {
        alert($('#enteredText').val());
        kendoWindow.close();
    });

    $(".delete-button").click(function (e) {
        $('#enteredText').val("");  // Clean previous value
        kendoWindow.open();
    });

    $(".delete-cancel").click(function () {
        kendoWindow.close();  // Cancel without showing
    });
});
```

See it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/x79yp/4/)